# How to resolve fortify scan issue- Code Correctness: Byte Array to String Conversion

Tags: java, fortify

I am getting this error in fortify Scan. Code Correctness: Byte Array to String Conversion

```
        final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteCharBuffer);
        final String base64EncodedPwd = new String(byteBuffer.array());
        technicalUserToSave.setPassword(base64EncodedPwd.toCharArray()); // M getting error at this line
```

TechnicalUser.java class

```
public class TechnicalUser implements Serializable
{

/**
 * Serialization version uid.
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * The password or secret of the technical user.
 */
@ApiModelProperty(name = "password", value = "Password")
@JsonProperty("password")
@Setter
private char[] password;
}
```